# Managing multiple database connections and data with foreachPartition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Will try to make it as clear as possible so an example isn't required as this has to be a concept that I didn't grasp properly and I'm struggling with rather than a problem with data or Spark code itself.

> I'm required to insert city data within their own database (**MongoDB**) and I'm trying to perform those upserts as fast as possible.

Take into account a sample DataFrame with the following, where I want to do some **upserts** against MongoDB based on, for example, **year**, **city** and **zone**.

`year - city - zone - num_business - num_vehicles`.

Having **groupedBy** those columns I'm just pending to perform the upsert into the DB.

Using the MongoDB Driver I'm required to instantiate several WriteConfigs to cope with multiple databases (**1 database per city**).

```
    // the 'getDatabaseWriteConfigsPerCity' method filters the 'df' so it only contains the docs from a single city.
    for (cityDBConnection <- getDatabaseWriteConfigsPerCity(df) {
        cityDBConnection.getDf.foreach(
            ... // set MongoDB upsert criteria.
        )
    }
```

Doing it that way works but still, more performance can be gained when using `foreachPartition` as I hope that those records within the DF are spread to the executors are more data is concurrently being upsert.

However, I get erroneous results when using `foreachPartition`. Erroneus because they seem incomplete. Counters are way off and such.

I suspect this is because, among the partitions, same keys are in different partitions and it's not until those are merged in the master when those are inserted to MongoDB as a single record.

Is there any way I can make sure partitions contain the **total** of documents related to an upsert key?

Don't really know if I'm being clear enough, but if it's still too complicated I will update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can make sure partitions contain the total of
>   documents related to an upsert key? if you do:

```
df.repartition("city").foreachPartition{...}
```

You can be sure that all records with same `city` are in the same partition (but there is probably more than 1 `city` per partition!)

Comment: That easy!? God, seems that I still need to quite read the API. Thanks a lot! :)